# Getting an error on: client.users.cache.get

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Getting an error all the time,

this is what i have,

```
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Malosa SentryBot started successfully');
client.users.cache.get('43437XXXXXX25418').send('Blabla')});
```

and this is the error:

```
    Malosa SentryBot started successfully
(node:8584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 's
end' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\discordbot2\new\Malosa-Sentry.js:1040:46)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
```

My id is 100% correct, i really don't know whats wrong.
the thing worked on v11, now on v12 it stopped working.

So what this does is when the bot starts it sends me an DM..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fetching the user. Always best to fetch than to rely on the cache.

```
client.on('ready', async() => {
   console.log('Malosa SentryBot started successfully');
   const user = await client.users.fetch('43437XXXXXX25418');

   user.send('Blabla');
});
```

Comment: that did the job, thanks.  Really weird that the one from Leonerrr_ not worked..

Comment: Not that weird, really. The code @Leonerrr_ posted is the same as yours with an extra variable. It still tries to get the user from the cache. On the other hand, the code above fetches the user, so (if your id is correct) you will receive it even if it's not cached.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting first the user and then, send the message

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get('<id>');
user.send('<message>');
```